A custom ERC20 Ethereum was transferred but the value shows 0
I received an amount of Ethereum, but the value shows 0. I would like to know how that is possible and what it is. I have been asked to add a custom token, and it shows a symbol (erc20) and the Ethereum logo. Is that a scam, and what do they want to do?

Please share the transaction hash so we can look into it.
